# error: ‘Namefunction’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I am new to C++ and I had problems with running this small example of inputing number of rectangle that we want to calculate the area each every one of them.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle{
    
private:
 float length;
 float width;
 
public:

 void input()
 {
  cout<<"length:"<<endl; cin>>length;
  cout<<"width:"<<endl; cin>>width;
 }
 
 void output()
 {
    cout<<length<<"\t"<<width<<"\t"<<area();
 }
 
 void inputAll(Rectangle a[],int n)
 {
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cout<<"Rectangle"<<(i+1)<<":"<<endl;
    a[i].input();
  }
 }
 
 void outputAll(Rectangle a[],int n)
 {
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    a[i].output();
  }
 }
 
 float area()
 {
  return length*width;
 }
};

int main()
{
  Rectangle a[30];
  int n;
  cout<<"input n:"; cin>>n;
  cout<<"Input all Rectangle data:"<<endl;
  a.inputAll(a,n);
  cout<<"Output all Rectangle data:"<<endl;
  a.outputAll(a,n);
  return 0;
}
```

Actually here are the errors in function **inputAll** and **outputAll**

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:61:5: error: request for member ‘inputAll’ in ‘a’, which is of non-class type ‘Rectangle [30]’
   a.inputAll(a,n);
     ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:63:5: error: request for member ‘outputAll’ in ‘a’, which is of non-class type ‘Rectangle [30]’
   a.outputAll(a,n);
     ^~~~~~~~~
```

I really dont know what caused the errors. Any help for this would be appreciated!

Comment: Those functions are namespaced within `Rectangle`, and because they're non-static they also need called via an instance of said class, i.e. `someRectangle.inputAll()`. Best to learn from a good book/tutorial that will explain this, instead of trying to do it thru trial and error.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to have those as members of `Rectangle`, which would presumably represent a single rectangle. Make them free functions instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Member functions must be called using the dot. You'll have to loop over your objects:

```
int main()
{
  Rectangle a[30];
  int n;
  cout<<"input n:"; cin>>n;
  cout<<"Input all Rectangle data:"<<endl;
  for (auto& r : a) {
    r.inputAll(a,n);
  }
  cout<<"Output all Rectangle data:"<<endl;
  for (auto& r : a) {
    r.outputAll(n);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Obviously, it doesn't make sense since you're already looping in those functions. You probably meant `inputAll` and `outputAll` to be free functions:

```
class Rectangle{
    
private:
 float length;
 float width;
 
public:

 void input()
 {
  cout<<"length:"<<endl; cin>>length;
  cout<<"width:"<<endl; cin>>width;
 }
 
 void output()
 {
    cout<<length<<"\t"<<width<<"\t"<<area();
 }
 
 float area()
 {
  return length*width;
 }
};

 
void inputAll(Rectangle a[],int n)
{
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cout<<"Rectangle"<<(i+1)<<":"<<endl;
    a[i].input();
  }
}
 
void outputAll(Rectangle a[],int n)
{
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    a[i].output();
  }
}
```

With this simple change, your previous main function will work.

Comment: Ahh okay thank you so much! It should put outside the class **Rectangle**.

Comment: @Erwinwin No problem! There is also static function that can also help, but I usually prefer free function for that. Free functions are better for encapsulation and can be placed in a different place than the class.

Answer (score -1):

inputAll() is a member function of the Rectangle class. Please access the inputAll() through a object of the Rectangle class.